# Using global variable in anonymous function

Tags: javascript, function, events

In html

```
<input type="file" multiple="multiple" (change)="getFileSizeandName($event)"/>
```

in file.ts

I have global variable

```
imageStringBase64: Array<string>;
```

and function call when event change trigger

```
getFileSizeandName(args) {
    let files = args.target.files;

    for (let i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
      let reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onload = (function (f) {
        return function(e) {
          console.log(e.target.result);
          this.imageStringBase64 = e.target.result;
        }
      })(files[i]);
      reader.readAsDataURL(files[i]);
    }
  }
}
```

When i use conole.log(e.target.result) in console printed stringBase64
Assign this.imageStringBase64 = e.target.result and have unexpected result, 
**this.imageStringBase64** is undefined. How use global var in anonymous function?

Comment: If it's a global variable don't put `this.` before it.

Comment: Barmar when i use without this i have error Canot find name imageStringBase64

Comment: Then it's not really a global variable, it's a property of an object.